# cmake finds Qt5Core, but build.make reports "Qt5::Core-NOTFOUND"

Tags: macos, cmake, qt5

Using MacOS Sierra, cmake 3.7.2 and qt 5.8.0 installed with homebrew. In this specific application, cmake completes without error but during build I get the following error:

```
CMakeFiles/CereLink.dir/build.make:174: *** target pattern contains no `%'.  Stop.
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/CereLink.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

The offending line has `Qt5::Core-NOTFOUND`

It is definitely a problem with this application as I have other Qt5-dependent applications that build correctly, and this application depends on an ExternalProject that links Qt5 which also builds correctly!

The problematic application can be found [online](https://github.com/cboulay/labstreaminglayer/tree/cerelink_app/Apps/BlackrockMicrosystems/Cerelink).

cmake seems to find Qt5 correctly. Using

```
FIND_PROGRAM(QT_QMAKE_EXECUTABLE_FINDQT
NAMES
    qmake qmake5 qmake-qt5
PATHS
    "${QT_SEARCH_PATH}/bin"
    "$ENV{QTDIR}/bin"
)
SET(QT_QMAKE_EXECUTABLE ${QT_QMAKE_EXECUTABLE_FINDQT} CACHE PATH "Qt qmake program.")
EXEC_PROGRAM(${QT_QMAKE_EXECUTABLE} ARGS "-query QT_INSTALL_PREFIX" OUTPUT_VARIABLE QT_INSTALL_PREFIX)
```

`message(${QT_INSTALL_PREFIX})` reports `/usr/local/Cellar/qt5/5.8.0_1`

`find_package(Qt5 COMPONENTS Core REQUIRED)` or `find_package(Qt5Core REQUIRED)` both seem to work correctly. See Additional Info below for evidence.

EDIT - Additional info:

- `message(${Qt5Core_FOUND})` prints `1`.
- `message(${Qt5Core_LIBRARIES})` prints `Qt5::Core`
- Manually setting `Qt5Core_DIR` instead of `CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH` does not change
  anything.
- Linking `Qt5Core` or `${Qt5Core_LIBRARIES}` (and additional includes) does not help.
- `get_target_property(QtCore_location Qt5::Core IMPORTED_LOCATION_RELEASE)`: `/usr/local/Cellar/qt5/5.8.0_1/lib/QtCore.framework/QtCore`

Comment: Which *configuration* (*CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE*) do you use for compile your project? I am unsure whether extracting *LOCATION* property for *IMPORTED* target (like `QT5::Core` one) is useful: According to [documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.7/prop_tgt/LOCATION.html), `this read-only property returns the value of the LOCATION_<CONFIG> property for an unspecified configuration <CONFIG> provided by the target.`.

Comment: What about `target_link_libraries(${target} PRIVATE Qt5Core)`? It might be that you can use the syntax `Qt5::Core` only if you import it with `find_package(Qt5 COMPONENTS Core REQUIRED)`.

Comment: @Tsyvarev, the problem persists whether using Debug or Release in Xcode, or Release in gnu-make. The call to `get_target_property` was only intended to show that the Qt5::Core 'target' exists and has a reasonable value.

Comment: @chadwick.boulay What does `message(STATUS "Qt5Core libraries: ${Qt5Core_LIBRARIES}")` print? Probably this will give a good hint where the problem is.

Comment: @chadwick.boulay Next I would try the following: 1) Delete the cache. 2) In the CMakeLists.txt, remove `set(CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH ${QT_INSTALL_PREFIX})` but 3) set the variable `Qt5Core_DIR` to the folder containing the file `Qt5CoreConfig.cmake`

Comment: @oLen, by the way, thank you very much for your help. Unfortunately that didn't change anything for me. I deleted some of my previous comments and put the info into the question.

Comment: I meant that it is not an *LOCATION* property which is used for link with the *QT5::Core* library. If *IMPORTED_LOCATION_DEBUG* property is set, then it is used for linking in Debug mode. Otherwise, *IMPORTED_LOCATION* property is used. Similar with Release mode. So you need to check *IMPORTED_LOCATION*, *IMPORTED_LOCATION_DEBUG* and *IMPORTED_LOCATION_RELEASE* properties instead.

Comment: @Tsyvarev, IMPORTED_LOCATION_RELEASE returns the same value: `/usr/local/Cellar/qt5/5.8.0_1/lib/QtCore.framework/QtCore`, but IMPORTED_LOCATION_DEBUG and IMPORTED_LOCATION are empty on my current configuration (gnu-make Release).

Comment: These properties do not depend from current configuration: they are set *unconditionally* in `Qt5CoreConfig.cmake`. So, only *Release* configuration of the imported target `Qt5::Core` can be used. You may tell CMake to use it for both configurations of your project: use `set(CMAKE_MAP_IMPORTED_CONFIG_RELEASE "RELEASE")`,  `set(CMAKE_MAP_IMPORTED_CONFIG_DEBUG "RELEASE")` before `find_package()` call or adjust [corresponding properties](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.7/prop_tgt/MAP_IMPORTED_CONFIG_CONFIG.html) for target `Qt5::Core` after that call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that I was overwriting `CMAKE_IMPORT_LIBRARY_SUFFIX` while configuring another 3rd party library. It took me a while to find this problem because it happens after all the calls to find Qt. I guess some aspect of finding/linking Qt is deferred until after configuration is complete and therefore after this variable was set, and these deferred aspects must use `CMAKE_IMPORT_LIBRARY_SUFFIX`. My solution was to create a new variable and set/use that manually instead of relying on `CMAKE_IMPORT_LIBRARY_SUFFIX`.

Answer (score 0):

In my case adding Qt5 path directly solved the problem:

`cmake .. -DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=/usr/local/opt/qt@5`